# Are there any differences between “update” and “edit”?

Tags: verbs, differences

Which one of those words I should use when something is changed.

> I update the record

OR

> I edit the record

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*Update* has the extra sense of adding newer information (or removing outdated information, per @trentcl's apt comment), whereas *edit* just has the sense of changing the information. Note that in the source below on the definition of *edit*, the definition listed as 1.c. mentions bringing about standardization or conformity, but not necessarily adding any new information.

Take for instance your name on some social media site. Let's say you first input it incorrectly. You could edit it to fix any typos, but that wouldn't necessarily be updating your name. Your name was the same regardless of the typo. Now let's say you legally changed your name and wanted to have that reflected on your social media, you could update your name, since what used to be true no longer is.

> **update** : to bring up to date [- M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/update)
>
> **edit** 1c : to alter, adapt, or refine especially to bring about conformity to a standard or to suit a particular purpose [- M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/edit)

Comment: It needs to be noted that the above distinction is not strict (except in certain technical contexts), and often the two words will be used interchangeably.

Comment: I already upvoted, but I think this answer would benefit from a little etymology. I mean, where does the word "edit" come from? "Bring up to date" is clear enough.

Comment: @MrLister, I'll comment the here since it wasn't asked for in the original question. From what I can tell, [*edit*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/edit) may have come from a variety of sources, all of which have their roots in the Latin *edere,* 'to give out, put out, or publish.' It is cognates with  [*edition*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/edition).

Comment: I'd suggest not using the phrase "add information" to define *update*, since you can also update something by removing (outdated) information (old contact info, for instance). Otherwise, good answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am from IT sphere. And in case of some MVC you may count next distinguish between these words:

> **edit** action is responsible for rendering the view (html form to POST data)
>
> **update** action is responsible for interacting with the model (db updates etc)

Comment: Yes, the words are used in the world of computer programming (a domain I am in as well), but it was not clear from your original question that you were asking about that. You are correct, *edit* renders the view to allow the user to change some information, and then the *update* will take that new information it received from the user and apply those changes where needed, thereby *updating* the model. The names don't apply to the actions the program does, per se, e.g., rendering an HTML form does not actually edit anything, but it allows the user to edit, thereby getting its name.

Comment: @Nolan: OK. I delete question